# How to execute a Python script on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded Visual Studio Code. I wrote some Python code but couldn't find a way to execute the code. Is there an in-built function to execute Python code using Visual Studio Code. If not, is there another way to do it?

Comment: First hit on google: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/34yvcm/using_visual_studio_code_with_python/

Comment: download python tools for visual studio

Comment: I have python tools for Visual Studio but it doesn't help with Visual Studio Code @ArashHatami

Comment: Oooops OK. So you should define Django's instalation directory for visual Studio to use it's IDLE for execute your code

Answer (score 0):

VS Code doesn't support execution of Python code out of the box.
You will need to either configure a task for this (see following link for further details https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks).
Or you could simply (easier) install the Python extension for VS Code, that will allow you to debug the python code.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python